# Binding Label property to Image property using javafx concurrency Task<Void>

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to update my JavaFX GUI after every 1 second using Task concuurency. I've icons `1.png`, `2.png`, `3.png` and so on. I'm using a while loop increments `i++`. I want to display those icons after every 1 second. I don't know how to update Image. I'm using `label.setGraphic()` method. I don't know how to use bind property here. I may be stark wrong. Please help me.

```
@Override
public void start() {
  ...
  image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/1.png"));
  imv=new ImageView(image);
  label1 = new Label();
  label1.setGraphic(imv);
  monitor(); //A SEPARATE METHOD CONTAINING TASK CODE
  ...
  new Thread(task1).start();
}

...
public void monitor() {
  task1=new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() {
      int i=1;
      while(true) {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(1000);
          updateMessage(""+i+".png");
          System.out.println("i: "+i);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        }
        i++;
        }
     }
  };
  label1.textProperty().bind(task1.messageProperty());
  ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please share a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Sure. I've uploaded to a repo. Read description also.
https://github.com/tmtanzeel/image-slideshow

Comment: The code in GitHub differs a bit from that showed in your question: `new Thread(task1).start();` which is `new Thread(task).start();` on GitHub and `label1.textProperty().bind(task1.messageProperty());` which is `imv.imageProperty().bind(task1.messageProperty());` on GitHub.

Comment: Please consider the code given on github. The code above was edited later on as I was trying different different approaches.

Comment: Then please update the code in your question to match the code in your question.

Comment: You should probably look into `Timeline`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you can not bind a `ReadOnlyStringProperty` to an `ObjectProperty<Image>`.

You should add a change listener ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html)) to the task message property ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html#addListener-javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener-)) and create an image which you then apply to your image view:

```
public void monitor() {
    task1 = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() {
            System.out.println("run called");
            int i = 1;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    updateMessage(i + ".png");
                    System.out.println("i: " + i);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    };
    task1.messageProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        System.out.println(newValue);
        Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/" + newValue));
        imv.setImage(image);
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**

The `ChangeListener` is represented by that Lambda expression in the given snippet. Please read the provided docs for more information.

Comment: According to your code on GitHub you also have to change `new Thread(task).start();` to `new Thread(task1).start();`

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not understanding things very clearly. Can you please make changes to the github program and give me a working version. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also i'm pretty new to Javafx.

Comment: Just replace the line `imv.imageProperty().bind(task1.messageProperty());` with the snippet I shared in my answer.

Comment: Replaced. Done.

Comment: Eclipse says:
The method bind(ObservableValue<? extends Image>) in the type Property<Image> is not applicable for the arguments (ReadOnlyStringProperty)

Comment: Yes that's the issue I was talking about in my answer.

Comment: Yes. But I'm not able to figure out what observable, oldValue and newValue are.

Comment: public void monitor() {
   task1=new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() {
     System.out.println("run called");
     int i=1;
     while(true) {
      try {
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       task1.messageProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
          System.out.println(newValue);
          Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/" + i+".png"));
          imv.setImage(image);
      });
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
       
      }
      i++;
     }
   }
   };
  }

Comment: Please provide a working program.Its a humble request. I've already wasted 4 days with this. You can share your code on github.

Comment: I updated my answer and referred some docs and extended the code. SO is not a Platform for tasks like "write my code please".

Comment: I've made all the changes you suggested in the guthib code. But it not displaying anything. Just a blank scene/stage.

Comment: The `monitor()` method i shared in my answer does not match the `monitor()` method you currently pushed on GitHub.

Comment: made changes. now its exactly the way you told. but now i'm getting exceptions.

run called
i: 1
1.png
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Main.lambda$0(Main.java:70)...so on for each iteration

Comment: You screwed up the initialization of your `ImageView imv;` its null, because you didn't initialize it.

Comment: Wow. that solved the exceptions. Initialized ImageView on line 70.
Added imv=new ImageView(); But still no image is displayed. I'm almost there. A little more help please.
Console output seems to be perfect.

Comment: You should just revert to the first version. Initialize the ImageView in the `start()` method, so the label has the imageView as graphic and not null.

Comment: Wow..It is working now. As perfectly as i wanted it to be. You have no idea how much thankful i am. I'll remember you all my life. I will mention you in project acknowledgemnt. :-)

Comment: I've also committed final bug free code on github on the same repo. Thanks a lot man. I've spent 100+ hours on this. Can have some beer now.